# Convert date string of format 1st, 2nd..nth-Month-YYYY to python date object

Tags: python, datetime

Can anyone help me with converting date strings like:

- 1st-October-1998
- 2nd-October-1998
- 3rd-October-1998
- nth-October-1998

I cannot see in [datetime.strptime() behaviour](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) that it allows for this format.

Comment: what is you expected format ?

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD (%Y-%m-%d), was trying to avoid regex.  Was hoping there was a library I could use

Comment: please take a look into my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with `dateutil.pareser` :

```
import dateutil.parser

s = "1st-October-1998"
d = dateutil.parser.parse(s)
print(d.date())
```

Output :

> 1998-10-01

Answer (score 0):

You can still use strptime however you need to removed the extra chars in data using regex

```
import re
date_string = "1st-October-1998"
def remove_extra_chars(ds):                                             
    return re.sub(r'(\d)(st|nd|rd|th)', r'\1', ds)
d = datetime.strptime(solve(date_string), '%d-%B-%Y')
print(d.strftime('%d-%B-%Y')) # output: 01-October-1998
print(d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) # output: 1998-10-01
```

Comment: Hi vim , OP is mentioned avoiding regex in comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Apparently I made a mistake in answering your question.**

To convert a string to date without using regex, we can try

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
s = '22nd-October-1998'
dt.strptime(s.replace(s[s.find('-')-2:s.find('-')], ''), '%d-%B-%Y').date()
```

The idea is to find the character `-` and then replace 2 characters before `-` with an empty string then convert it using `datetime.strptime()`.

---

In a DataFrame, we can do it by using pandas native functions. Suppose that the DataFrame is `df` and the date string format column is `Date`, then we can convert the column to date time format by using

```
    pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].replace(dict.fromkeys(['st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th'], ''),
                                      regex=True), format='%d-%B-%Y')
```

The idea is to replace the substrings `['st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th']` with an empty string then convert the column using [pandas.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).